# struct vector works

Tags: c++, struct

I did a mistake in my program, I wrote

```
struct vector<int> v;
```

instead of

```
vector<int> v;
```

but it seems that the compiler doesn't care: http://codepad.org/TCPb8p2u

Why does it work? Is there some differencies with or without `struct`?

Comment: I think the question is: “if this is valid, does it do what I wanted to express?”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write `class`, it would also work.

```
class vector<int> v;
```

See this: http://www.ideone.com/EoJxk

This is actually old C style. The C++ Standard calls it **elaborated-type-specifier** in section §3.4.4.

The keyword `struct` (or `class`, `enum`) is sometimes used to **remove** ambiguities, or to make **hidden** names *visible* to the compiler. Consider the following example from the Standard itself (from section §9.1/2). Please notice that there exists a `struct` with name `stat` and with exactly same also exists a *function*:

```
struct stat {
    // ...
};
stat gstat; // use plain stat to define variable

int stat(struct stat*); // redeclare stat as function

void f()
{
    struct stat* ps; // struct prefix needed to name struct stat
    // ...
    stat(ps); //call stat()
    // ...
}
```

§9.1/2 says,

> A class definition introduces the
>   class name into the scope where it is
>   defined and **hides any class, object,
>   function, or other declaration of that
>   name in an enclosing scope (3.3)**. If a
>   class name is declared in a scope
>   where an object, function, or
>   enumerator of the same name is also
>   declared, **then when both declarations
>   are in scope, the class can be
>   referred to only using an
>   elaborated-type-specifier (3.4.4)**.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of C++ that's used to resolve ambiguity between a variable and type with the same name. I believe they're called 'elaborate type specifiers.'

You can use a keyword to tell the compiler exactly what you mean, when there would normally be ambiguity.

Take this for example:

```
int x = 0;
class x { };

// Compiler error! Am I refering to the variable or class x?
x y;

// This is okay, I'm telling the compiler which x I'm referring to.
class x y;
```

This can also be used to specify enums and unions, not just structs and classes, though you can only have one user-defined type with the same name.

Comment: thanks, this is new to me: in C++ you can declare variables and classes with the same name!!

Comment: You also shouldn't do it. Ever. :)

Answer (score 2):

The others have already explained it that what you uses is called *elaborated type specifier*, which can be used for name unhiding and ambiguity resolution.

However, what also works here is one curious feature of C++ language, which states that *class-key* (i.e. `class` or `struct` keyword) used in class declaration is not required to agree with the *class-key* used in the elaborated type specifier. E.g. you can declare your class with `class` keyword and then later refer to it with `struct` keyword (and vice versa). There's no error in it

```
class S {};

int main() {
  struct S s; // OK, 's' has type `S` (i.e. `class S`)
}
```

Standard `std::vector` template class is declared with keyword `class`, but there's no error in referring to it as `struct std::vector`, which is what you did in your example.

And no, it makes no difference whether in your declaration of `v` you use `class`, `struct` or nothing at all.